# Combine two hard drives

Tags: 12.04, server, hard-drive, lvm

I have a PC with 2 physical hard drives, each is 500 GB (sda and sdb)

I'd like to combine them in one large hard drive (1T).

I couldn't find a clear approach on how to do it. I tried LVM with no luck. Any idea?

Comment: RAID 0 could do that, but at the expense of reliability.